# Referencing a .NET framework 4.7.2 from a v4.0

Tags: vb.net, .net-framework-version

I'm working on a project thats a couple of projects that are a few years old, and have been working fine for all that time. The .NET framework v4.0 project is calling the v4.7.2 in a dll. I know that can create issues but we've had this for years with no issues. As well it seems none of my other coworkers are having the same build issues I'm having.
The project loads fine and shows no errors, but on build there are errors. I'm using the same version of VS that everyone else is and pulling the same branch for each project that everyone else is.
None of us know why this happening so I figured I would try here.

Comment: You should include the text of the errors.

Comment: Nope, genuine question. Only error is a "Type <4.7.2 component> is not defined"  at the one spot this application is calling the other.

Comment: @Ian: Unfortunately, your post needs more details. You may start by opening _Visual Studio Installer_, and under _Individual Components_, ensure that you have both the _.NET Framework 4.7.2 targeting pack_ and _.NET Framework 4.7.2 SDK_ installed.

Comment: I would NEVER have a project with a lower .net framework referencing a higher .net framework .dll. That is JUST A REALLY bad idea. I not sure why that worked all these years, but you ALWAYS for the last 30+ years in our industry been able to go forward with software, but not backwards. In other words, a .net 4.8 can play nice and reference a .net 4.0 .dll. However, the reverse has NEVER been the case nor recommended. Simply upgrade the .net of the project referencing the newer .dll .net framework, or downgrade the newer library back down to 4.0. Bad idea here, and now you paying the price.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Yup, feel like thats all pretty obvious but this is stuff that goes beyond my time here so out my of hands and its not in the schedule to upgrade these projects so we're kinda stuck where were at. Obviously thats the best solution but I wouldn't be on here if I could do that

Comment: Ok, that is the hand you been dealt here. All us developers are often dealt such a deck of cards to work with. However, still saying, its not a good idea. We always as a rule been able to "move forward" so to speak in our industry, but trying to go backwards or using older code to consume some newer library simple not a supported use case. I am confident to say that  .net compatibly probably been the "best case" and "best" supported for any framework system from any vendor in our industry.  In fact, .net 4.8 can easy consume .net 2.0 .dll's, but certainly not the other way around.

Comment: In most cases, if you re-compile the older code, it in 99% of cases will work without changes anyway. So, unfortunately, the best advice is to either downgrade current code to the lowest common framework, or re-compile the older code to a newer framework. I can't really much think of any other way this can reliably work. As noted, newer framework is happy to consume older framework code, but the reverse is simply not supproted.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? What version of Visual Studio are your colleagues using? What version of Visual Studio was the project built with? (open the _.sln_ file with Notepad) Have you enabled diagnostic output (Tools -> Options... -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity) in Visual Studio? Are you using any NuGet packages? If so, what is the _Default package management format_ set to in _NuGet Package Manager_ (Tools -> Options... -> NuGet Package Manager -> General)?

Comment: Please add the detailed error message to your OP.  Also, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. The _minimal reproducible example_ should mimic what you're doing which means that you should have code for both .NET Framework 4.7.2 and .NET Framework 4. Since, .NET Framework 4, was released with both a _Client_ version and a _Full_ version, specify which one you're using.

Answer (score -2):

```
## "MySnippet.link"

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="0.7.5.5" name="MySnippet.link"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**